# css and js is not working in blog detail page wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVhir.png)

CSS and JS is not working in blog detail page

Comment: have you load static  `{% load static %}`  ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.